# How to make function as argument in C without having a static function?

Tags: c

In JavaScript, I could simply do something like `runCode((arg1) => { sampleFunction(arg1); })`, but I can't do that in C. I tried declaring functions in a function as a workaround (as I'm making a function that does stuff with only itself), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: C does not support anonymous nor nested functions.  You will need a top-level, named function somewhere.

Comment: @soshimee post the code that _doesn't seem to work_.  It should have.

Answer (score 2):

In C you would pass a function pointer:

```
void f(int arg1) {
}


void f2(void (*fp)(int), int arg1) {
  fp(arg1);
}


int main() {
  f2(&f, 42);
  return 0;
}
```

You would need to pass in data as separate arguments.  If you want f2 to support different function signatures you can do that by passing in a `union` of each type.  In practice, you often see struct being passed in via a void pointer:

```
  f3(void (*fp)(union { struct a a, struct b b} *data), union { struct a a, struct b b} *data);
  f4(void (*fp)(void *data), void *data);
```

f3 would be type checked at compile time, while f4 would fail at run-time if you try to cast data the wrong type.

If you wanted to create a function at run-time, then you would have to generate object code somehow (i.e. by compiling a function, load it possible via dlopen).  It's rarely done.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "without having a static function".

Comment: @jamesdlin There are no `static` functions in the answer, so answer demos a usage _without having a static function_.

Comment: @chux It seems evident to me that the intent of the question is not about functions that use the `static` keyword but about statically defined functions.

Comment: What is a non-statically defined function?  I get that op didn't mean a static function.  How is sampleFunction in question "non-static"?  Or is that runCode allows arbitrary arguments?

Comment: A non-statically-defined function is one that is created dynamically (at runtime).  That does not exist in C.  `sampleFunction` in the question is *not* the function being asked about; the OP wants the equivalent of the *closure* `(arg1) => { sampleFunction(arg1); }`, which is an anonymous function that takes an argument and calls `sampleFunction` on it.  The OP clearly is not asking about the keyword `static` because that question would make *no sense* since C functions by default are *not* `static`.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant anonymous functions, but if that is not possible in C, I would just have to go with this.

Comment: `&f` is redundant. When a function is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the function, per C 2018 7 4. Even if you applied `*` to that pointer, it would get converted back: `f`, `&f`, `*&f`, `*******&f`, and `*********f`, and `*&*&*&f` all end up as the same value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, I know, but I thought it was clearer that way.